# Simultaneous congruences to different moduli

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, congruences

For some natural numbers $a,b$, let it be known that $b\leq 8$:
$$b\cdot 99a = x68y - 8$$
where we read $x68y$ as *x-thousand sixhundred and eighty-y*.
What I have established is:
$$\begin{cases}b\mid (x68y-8)&\Longleftrightarrow x68y\equiv 8\pmod{b}\\
 99a\mid (x68y-8)&\Longleftrightarrow x68y\equiv 8\pmod{99a}\end{cases} $$

The objective is to determine $a,b$ and for that I thought I would check all possibilities for $b: 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1$ and see whether 99 divides any of the numbers produced in each case. This turns out to be quite tedious.
What can I do to optimize my work?

Comment: Just an idea, but if $9$ divides a number, then it divides the sum of its digits.  The digits of $x68y$ are either $x, 6, 8, y$ if $y \geq 8$, or $x, 6, 7, (10+y-8)$ if $y \leq 7$.

Comment: We actually have much better than that. $9$ divides $x68y-8$ which means $9$ divides $x+y+6$ hence $x+y\in\{3,12\}$.

Comment: That's only true if $y \geq 8$.  As I should have said, if $y < 8$, then the digits of $x68y - 8$ are $x, 6, 7, (10+y-8)$, and you get $9$ divides $x + 6 + 7 + 10 + y - 8 = x + y + 15$.

Comment: Ah, you are right.

Comment: Oh, but now i see that this doesn't really matter: they give the same equation mod $9$ since $15 \equiv 6 \pmod{9}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $b=3$ and $a=9$. Also $x=2, y=1$.
On a hunch I checked whether $b=3$ that means $x68y\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ i.e $3\mid (x68y-2)$ which is the same as $3\mid (x+y+14-2)$ (sum of digits). Since it seems unlikely that $y$ is even I took $y=1$ that leaves $x\in\{2,5,8\}$ and on my first attempt, indeed $99\mid (2681-8)$ as required.

$99\mid (x68y-8)$ is the key. Makes this problem 99 times easier.

Doesn't have to be only this solution, though. $b=1, a=27$ is also a possibility unless I'm missing something.